# YouCompleteme works but can not complete using TAB

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I installed YouCompleteMe using vundle.
Then installed all plugins and installed YCM using

```
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

This is how my vimrc looks:

```
syntax on
set expandtab
set cindent
set tabstop=4
retab
set shiftwidth=4
set hlsearch
set paste
set ic
set number
colorscheme molokai
set t_Co=256

set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat' 
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'sjl/gundo.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'Valloric/ListToggle'

call vundle#end()            " required


filetype plugin indent on 

"options for syntastic"

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['pep8', 'pylint', 'python']
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 1
let g:syntastic_error_symbol = "X"
let g:syntastic_style_error_symbol = ">"
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = "!"
let g:syntastic_style_warning_symbol = ">"
let g:syntastic_echo_current_error=1
let g:syntastic_enable_balloons = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_jump=1

"Gundo options"

nnoremap <F5> :GundoToggle<CR>

"CtrlP options"
let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP'

"Powerline stuff"
python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python powerline_setup()
python del powerline_setup

set laststatus=2
```

YCM works but I can't switch between the suggestions using TAB, only using Down and Up arrows and accepting with Enter.

Why is happening this? Is another program using the TAB key?

thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Use YouCompleteMe's issue tracker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was due to the "set paste" line in my .vimrc

so, I removed it, and when I want to paste large blocks of code in vim, I just write :set paste to enable it or :set nopaste to disable it. This toggle can be also mapped to f10 or any key.

Comment: To paste 'whatever', you can also use the `:r !xclip -o` or whatever it is you use for your clipboard.  Reading the contents directly from clipboard into the file will avoid doing abbreviates and other completions.  And you won't need to remember the state of `paste`.  This comment, of course, doesn't fix your issue, but is a 'trick' that you may end up adopting.

Answer (score 18):

By configuring `set paste`, you're effectively disabling *all* mappings and abbreviations.

You only need that set when you actually paste text in terminal Vim! It's best to bind this to a key. As mappings cannot be used when the option is set, Vim provides a special option for this:

```
:set pastetoggle=<F10>
```

#### Further commentary

As the `~/.vimrc` is sourced at the beginning of Vim startup (when files passed to it haven't yet been loaded), the  `retab` is ineffective; just drop it. If you really want automatic reindenting for opened files, you'd have to employ an `:autocmd BufRead * retab` for that, but I'd advise against that.

Comment: This solved my problem immediately. Thanks a lot Ingo Karkat!